# what happens to a currently running quartz job when server is shutdown

Tags: quartz-scheduler

We have a SQL based quartz scheduler. There is a job that processes 100k records and runs for 2 hours. If a server shutdown is initiated with the job still running, will the job start again after the server is restarted?

Answer (score 3):

Check

[RequestsRecovery](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/) - if a job "requests recovery", and it is executing during the time of a 'hard shutdown' of the scheduler (i.e. the process it is running within crashes, or the machine is shut off), then it is re-executed when the scheduler is started again. In this case, the JobExecutionContext.isRecovering() method will return true.

As long as you have JDBCData store, this will work.

Comment: Thanks. So what happens if the Quartz job is half way done, and server shutdown command is issued? Will the shutdown process wait for the quart job to finish?

Answer (score 1):

You need to store your scheduler details JDBC JobStore when you are creating Scheduler factory with JDBC configuration properties.

After that, you can extract it from the metadata and according to the failure time you can retrieve your scheduler details and resume it according to your requirement.

Please refer:- [Quartz Scheduler using JDBC JobStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306354/quartz-scheduler-using-jdbc-jobstore)

One more alternative way is that you can create your own Scheduler Listener and assign it to the scheduler. Reference :- https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/quartz/quartz-scheduler-tutorial/