# Quartz Scheduler using JDBC JobStore

Tags: java, struts2, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

For the first time i stored the jobs and scheduled them using crontrigger with the below code.

```
package com.generalsentiment.test.quartz;

import static org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule;
import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.newJob;
import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.newTrigger;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.quartz.CronTrigger;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerFactory;
import org.quartz.SchedulerMetaData;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class CronTriggerExample {

    public void run() throws Exception {
        Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CronTriggerExample.class);

        System.out.println("------- Initializing -------------------");

        Xml config = new Xml("src/hibernate.cfg.xml", "hibernate-configuration");

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.setProperty("org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName", "ALARM_SCHEDULER");
        prop.setProperty("org.quartz.threadPool.class",   
                        "org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool");
        prop.setProperty("org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount", "4");

        prop.setProperty("org.quartz.threadPool
                        .threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread", "true");

        prop.setProperty("org.quartz.jobStore.class", 
                          "org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX");
        prop.setProperty("org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass", 
                          "org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate");
        prop.setProperty("org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource", "tasksDataStore");
        prop.setProperty("org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix", "QRTZ_");
        prop.setProperty("org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold", "60000");
        prop.setProperty("org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered", "false");

        prop.setProperty("org.quartz.dataSource.tasksDataStore.driver", 
              config.child("session-factory").children("property").get(1).content());
        prop.setProperty("org.quartz.dataSource.tasksDataStore.URL", config.child("session-
             factory").children("property").get(2).content());
        prop.setProperty("org.quartz.dataSource.tasksDataStore.user", config.child("session-
             factory").children("property").get(3).content());
        prop.setProperty("org.quartz.dataSource.tasksDataStore.password", 
             config.child("session-factory").children("property").get(4).content());
        prop.setProperty("org.quartz.dataSource.tasksDataStore.maxConnections", "20");

        // First we must get a reference to a scheduler
        SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(prop);
        Scheduler sched = sf.getScheduler();

        System.out.println("------- Initialization Complete --------");

        System.out.println("------- Scheduling Jobs ----------------");

        // jobs can be scheduled before sched.start() has been called

        // job 1 will run exactly at 12:55 daily
        JobDetail job = newJob(SimpleJob.class).withIdentity("job2", "group2").build();

        CronTrigger trigger = newTrigger().withIdentity("trigger2", "group2")
                                          .withSchedule(cronSchedule("00 15 15 * * 
                                                         ?")).build();

        Date ft = sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
        System.out.println(sched.getSchedulerName());
        System.out.println(job.getKey() + " has been scheduled to run at: " + ft
                + " and repeat based on expression: "
                + trigger.getCronExpression());

        System.out.println("------- Starting Scheduler ----------------");

        /*
         * All of the jobs have been added to the scheduler, but none of the
         * jobs will run until the scheduler has been started. If you have
         * multiple jobs performing multiple tasks, then its recommended to
         * write it in separate classes, like SimpleJob.class writes
         * organization members to file.
         */
        sched.start();

        System.out.println("------- Started Scheduler -----------------");

        System.out.println("------- Waiting five minutes... ------------");
        try {
            // wait five minutes to show jobs
            Thread.sleep(300L * 1000L);
            // executing...
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        System.out.println("------- Shutting Down ---------------------");

        sched.shutdown(true);

        System.out.println("------- Shutdown Complete -----------------");

        SchedulerMetaData metaData = sched.getMetaData();


        System.out.println("Executed " + metaData.getNumberOfJobsExecuted() + " jobs.");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        CronTriggerExample example = new CronTriggerExample();
        example.run();
    }
    }
```

And the details are stored in Tables - `QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS`, `QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS` & `QRTZ_TRIGGERS`

My doubt is How to schedule the jobs that are stored in DB. How to display the list of jobs in a jsp page & how to trigger them automatically.
Ours is a struts2 application with Hibernate3 ORM. I am trying to initialize the quartz scheduler when the application loads. But am unable to.

Comment: I'm almost certain that the Quartz manual will tell you how to trigger and schedule jobs.

Comment: The documentation @ Java Quartz site - http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/

Comment: You seem to keep posting the same question over and over again - why not just use the original question?

Comment: In reference to the code in the post. can you guys suggest me.. how to implement the same in container environment. i.e., quartz getting initilised at startup. I tried the steps as mentioned in this link but its not working... http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/cookbook/ServletInitScheduler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Date ft = sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

When this is called, your job would be scheduled for the next fire time. The scheduled job would stored in the appropriate DB tables.
To Display the list of jobs on a jsp, you should persist you job key as well as custom description of what your job entails to another DB table so that during retrieval you can retrieve this custom description as well as data Quartz persist into its own tables.
Triggering this jobs automatically is something Quartz handles for you. Once the crone expression is set to what is desired and your Job class implements `org.quartz.Job`, Quartz would run the `execute()`  method at your desired next fire time

Comment: I have written a blog post on Quartz that uses a REST API to schedule jobs and uses liquibase to manage database migrations.    http://juliuskrah.com/tutorial/2017/10/06/persisting-dynamic-jobs-with-quartz-and-spring/

Answer (score 1):

```
JobDetail job = newJob(SimpleJob.class).withIdentity("job2", "group2").build();
```

this means you will have a class named `SimpleJob` that implements `org.quartz.Job`. In that class `execute()` method need to be implemented. Job is triggered automatically at the time you specified by `cron expression`. That execute method is called when job is triggered.

Comment: Yes, the job was executed and its details were stored in DB. But how should the job execute automatically with the DB info ?

Comment: that is implementation of quartz...and thats y u are using it.. :-)